# how to make two number and text on same line

Tags: java, println, system.out

okay so i cant seem to get the variable "mChoc" and "fChoc" on the same line as "you should eat" and "chocolate bars if you are male/female to maintain your weight." could i get some help. ive been reading all over my text book and cant seem to find a solution. I need to keep the the `"%1.2f"`

```
System.out.println("\nYou should eat "); 
System.out.printf ("%1.2f", mChoc);
System.out.println(" chocolate bars if you are male to maintain your weight!");

System.out.println("You should eat");  
System.out.printf("%.2f", fChoc); 
System.out.println(" chocolate bars if you are female to maintain your weight!");
```

Comment: javascript tag seems to be wrong.

Comment: That is very strange JavaScript... You'd probably should use `console.log`... If it is Java reading documentation on each method you use is required step before asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Use `print` instead of `println` (the second adds a newline), **or** you could use one call like

```
System.out.printf("You should eat %.2f chocolate bars if "
        + "you are female to maintain your weight!%n", fChoc);
```